# What's the point of the subscripts in the triple product rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$\left ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial  y}\right )_z \left ( \frac{\partial y}{\partial  z}\right )_x\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial  x}\right )_y = -1$$

I don't understand what the subscripts are there for. I was thinking it meant that the partial derivative is specified on a particular contour of, say, $z$. This seems to turn the partial derivative from a function of two variables to a function of one variable? But why is this necessary? Why not just write

> $$\left ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial  y}\right )\left ( \frac{\partial y}{\partial  z}\right )\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial  x}\right )= -1$$

Comment: Sometimes such a subscript refers to the partial derivative w.r.t. to this variable, i.e. $z_x=\frac\partial{\partial x}z$. Therefore your notation migth be a shorthand for $$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z=\frac\partial{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)$$ And for the other terms the same respectively. This would be a legitimate difference.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article [Triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) explicitly explains the notation:

> Note: In each factor the variable in the numerator is considered to be an implicit function of the other two. In each factor the subscripted variable is being held constant.